Zigbee with Philips Hue in range but not found

I have 7 of this EGLO bulb. 4 in the dining room and 3 in the sitting room. The bulbs in each room are in line of sight of each other.

The Hue Hub is upstairs while the two rooms are downstairs.

The light bulbs in the dining room are physically further away from the Philips Hue hub but have no trouble being found by Hue and control is fast and trouble free.

The bulbs in the sitting room are physically closer, which has at least as much concrete wall between them and the hub as the dining room bulbs, but only 2 can be found but Hue and none can be reliably controlled.


I thought that Zigbee devices effectively create a mesh, so that the dining room bulbs should allow the sitting room bulbs to connect effectively.
Distance should not be a problem for the sitting room bulbs, if the dining room has no trouble being found and controlled but the sitting room bulbs have this exact issue:

2 of 3 found and controlled only from the ’room’ switch in the Hue app, cannot be controlled individually
1 of 3 not found at all

I have tried all sorts of things like resetting the hue, turning on only the problem lights etc.
What other factors could I look into?

Have you tried swapping a bulb which works with one which doesn’t? To check if it’s the location or the bulb itself.

@jcaron No, but I added another new bulb (they are all new) to the undetectable/un controllable group) and it behaved the same.

@jsotola Specifics provided

Some bulbs have compatibility issues depending on their firmware version, and even devices bought all at the same time may come with different versions out of the box. You need to be able to determine if it’s the bulb or the location. Also sometimes you need the new device to be in range of the bridge directly for the join procedure (before you can move it away).

So, I tried this and the bulb does not appear in the Hue app. Just can’t find it. What else can I do to make an EGLO bulb get found, or to update it? The EGLO app doesn’t seem useful in this regard.

What did you try? Moving the bulb to a location where another one works, or moving it close to the bridge? Also, is the bulb still in join mode? If not, you may need to reset it so it restarts the join procedure. This usually involves switching the bulb on/off 5 or 6 times with the right intervals, see the bulb's manual.

What I have found is that if the device is near the hub and sometimes works, then it does not use another device as a repeater.  If the device is far enough away and fails to connect directly every time, then the mesh is used. Its an annoying feature and it would be so much easier if you tell it when to use a repeater.
One solution is to see if you are able to get a larger antenna for your hub.
